# LinearRegression algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Which algorithm from algebra is used to implement `LinearRegression()` function in scikit-learn?

Comment: which library are you talking about?

Comment: I am using sklearn.

Comment: There is also a "statsmodels" module which provides ".ols()" function.I just want to know the algorithm (Numerical Linear Algebra) used in implementation of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> LinearRegression fits a linear model with coefficients w = (w1, ..., wp) to minimize the residual sum of squares between the observed targets in the dataset, and the targets predicted by the linear approximation.

So LinearRegression uses OLS i.e. Ordinary Least Squares regression

Comment: But I want to know a matrix factorization method used in its implementaion for better accuracy and stability

Comment: If you look at the documentation under: solver ( https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ridge_regression.html), you have different possibilities. default is set up to auto but you can define another option like cholesky, svd, etc... Is that what kind of factorization matrix you are looking for?

Comment: When you post a quote, it is arguably a good practice to include the relevant link, too ("documentation" is quite a vague term, and scikit-learn documentation is huge).

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn is open source, and the source is available on GitHub.

The code for `LinearRegression` is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9cfacf1540a991461b91617c779c69753a1ee4c0/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py) so from the comments:

```
From the implementation point of view, this is just plain Ordinary
Least Squares (scipy.linalg.lstsq) or Non Negative Least Squares
(scipy.optimize.nnls) wrapped as a predictor object.
```

If you want greater detail, you can read the code.